# AngularFire2 iterate through array of objects

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire, angularfire2

I have the following Firebase database structure:

```
orders {
  $uid { // user UID
    order {
    // ...
    }
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to get all orders, this way:

```
public getOrders() {
  this.db.list('/orders).subscribe(items => {
    items.forEach(item => {
      console.log(item);
    })
  })
}
```

[image: items]

My question is, how I can get all orders ?
Because now, I can't iterate through `item`.

Comment: For example, if I'm trying to do `items[0].length` the output is `undefined`

Comment: Of course, because only `items` is a `Array`, but it's children are `Objects` which don't have `.length` property.

Comment: You have a right, I have tried to convert each object to array but unsuccessfully :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so finally I could resolve it in the following way:

```
public getOrders() {
  this.db.list('/orders).subscribe(items => {
    items.forEach(item => {
      Object.keys(item).map(key=>item[key]).map(order => {
        console.log(order);
      })
    })
  })
}
```

So, first we getting all orders, then iterate using `forEach` through each object with orders. Then, using `Object.keys` we can access to the order of each user.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the result(`items`) from the `Firebase Database` in a `variable` and after, use the variable in your Angular template(HTML).

**Firebase DB:**
*/orders/*

```
[{
    "userId1": {
      "name": "Michael",
      "value": "55$"
    }
  },
  {
    "userId1": {
      "name": "Michael",
      "value": "55$"
    }
  }
]
```

**Component's logic**

```
databaseOrders;
public getOrders() {
  this.db.list('/orders).subscribe(items => {
    this.databaseOrders = items;
  })
}
```

**Component's Template**

```
<div *ngIf="databaseOrders" class="orders">
  <article *ngFor="let order of databaseOrders; let i = index"> 
    <span class="ordered-by">{{order[i].name}}<span> 
    <b class="order-value">{{order[i].value}}</b>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Marian07, it's useful but in this case my intention is to calculate orders and access to property of each order. So, do you know how I can access to each order ?

Comment: See the AngularFire2 `lists` : https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md